# cannot step into code access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using Access 2010 I cannot step into the code I have written for a form in Access.

Shouldn't I be able to step through it using the F8 key?

Does this indicate a damaged install of Access?

Comment: **Please provide us with some code, so we can help you better.** That can happen If your Sub or Function takes arguments, or more probably it is an event triggered code. Or you have some other window in edit mode (e.g. in excel, if you double click on cell and remain in this edit mode, VBA UI will not respond).

Comment: Set a Breakpoint in your code, then you can use [F8], etc., once you've reached it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several conditions required for F8 to work.

You cannot be in a forms code module and hit F8 – it will not work since forms code is a class module.

If the code module is a class module, then again you cannot hit F8 when looking at code in that module (so a forms code module, and a code module that is a class object will not work.

Eg these:

[image]

Also if you hit F8 inside of a SUB or function that requires “parameters” then again F8 will not work. (since parameters are required).

So code in a class module will not work with F8 since you need to create an “instance” of that class object in code. Of course any routine (function/sub) that creates an instance of the class object will THEN allow F8 to step though such class object code.

And for a form, if you introduce a break line, or place a stop command in the code, then when the code runs, and encounters the breakpoint (or stop command), then at THAT point in time since a “instance” of the object exists, then F8 to single step will work.

So the difference between code/objects that must be instantiated before F8 works needs to be keep in mind.

Thus again, you can use F8 inside of forms code modules (they are class objects), but ONLY when an instance of the object (in this case a form) ahs been created and is running. So F8 can step though such code, but F8 cannot be used to start+run+debug such code until such time an instance of the object has been created.

So function/sub cannot have parameters, and cannot be in a form since such modules are class modules, and as noted you cannot use f8 inside of a class module either.

Answer (score 0):

Try ALT+F11, then F8. Not my normal procedure. I found it by experimentation - pressing keys to see what happens.

Comment: Was My answer useful? I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could force and error, like "mxgbox whatever" at the beginning of your class module. When VBA shows you the error message box you can click on "debug" and then continue with F8.

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the VB Editor by hitting Alt+F11 then you can enter a break into any code on a code line - that way the code will stop there, and you can use F8 to step through or F5 to resume and run.

Oh, and if you don't know, you can enter a break by clicking the side panel or by pressing F9 on a particular line.